# Check if a string is in a file

Tags: c, string, file, binaryfiles, strstr

I've been trying to make a program that checks if a file contains another file's. (like an anti Virus). I tried to use strstr() to do so but apparently the strstr() does not work so well.

What is the best solution to check if a file contains another file in it?
Edit: I'm working on binary files.

Comment: You can use [longest common subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem).

Comment: Your best solution is to rewrite this question as I do not understand what you are trying to achieve and also what you have tried

Comment: Post the code. Also, fix the spelling on your message. If you loaded the files correctly strstr should work.

Comment: The code is somewhere about 150 lines of code...
strstr() worked only when the file contained the other file at the beginning. @UDKOX

Comment: File is only stream of bytes. They are very often binary, so treating them with strstr() is incorrect.

Comment: So what do you suggest me to do? @MichałMielec

Comment: Debug your code.  Use a debugger, or print intermediate results, to narrow down your problem, until you'll know where it is located.

Comment: You have to know what kind of file you are looking for. Ex. Is it text file or binary, or if it contains some common markups etc Then read this file as bytes not string, and then according to proper standard try to parse it.

Comment: Also if file contains some zero bytes, strings functions would not read them completely. Zero bytes \0 terminates C strings

Comment: Deja vu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37225382/how-to-check-if-a-string-exists-in-a-binary-file

Comment: The str* library functions are useless for this.  I'm afraid that you are going to have to write some code.

Comment: But there are functions in C also for bare bytes manipulating like memcmp() memcopy(), fread(). So don't be afraid :)

Answer (score 1):

The way to compare arbitrary sequences of bytes in C is with `memcmp`. This is a Standard C89 function.

Comment: Note: this will not work for large files that can not fit into memory

Comment: @NemanjaTrifunovic Only if one wants the whole file in memory. You can do comparisons a chunk at a time if you need to deal with overly big files. Or memory map the files.

Comment: `The memmem() function finds the start of the first occurrence of the
substring needle of length needlelen in the memory area haystack of
length haystacklen.` Is for strings, not binary data. Won't think it will work, haven't tried myself though.

Comment: @Jens: I agree.

But also I think it's a bit more complicated, because you do not know the position at which one file can be in the other file, so you would need to check all possible positions which is not optimal.

Comment: @UDKOX No, `memmem` works for binary data according to the man page. But it is a GNU extension, not a C89 function.

Comment: I guess you are right. If my source is correct and `memmem` uses `memcmp` it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm which is one of the best solutions for the problem you have.

It might be worth exploring and learning about other solutions to the string matching problem as well.
See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm for the list of string searching algorithms.

Resources to learn about KMP algorithm:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ogqPWJSftE

*Note: you can use these algorithms on bytes as well.*

Comment: But without treating these files as strings. :D KMP on bytes is possible

Comment: @MichałMielec: Yes, that was my idea how to use those algorithms in this case :) I added a note about this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is the `memmem` function, which finds a subsequence in a data file.
Compared with `strstr`, the `memmem` function does not stop at `\0`, which let's you find any data in any file.